# BIOS Boot Priority menu shows two different items with the same name

Tags: boot, graphics, 16.04

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm setting the boot priority through the UEFI BIOS Utility (my machine is not dual booted). The options under the Boot Priority section are:

```
P1: HL-DT-ST BD-RE WH14NS40 (no idea what that garbage means ;)  
ubuntu  
ubuntu  
Crucial_CT512MX100SSD1 (488386MB) (I think those are the specs of my SSD)
```

I have no idea what the difference is between the two "ubuntu" options. They do differ - one boots into a very minimal graphics mode, while the other boots with the graphics card working (although its cooperation appears to be intermittent -  typical Ubuntu ;).
What's the difference between the two "ubuntu" options (other than what I've already noticed, i.e. what is causing the difference and how does it affect the rest of my setup)? Alternatively, should I be booting into one of the other options?

Thanks a lot for any feedback!

P.S. I've been having some trouble installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my system - an occasional login loop, sometimes the screens go on but don't show anything, sometimes crazier things happen ;). This is a new installation - Ubuntu 14.04 was running like a charm on this machine a week ago (i.e. I don't think the hardware is at fault). On that previous Ubuntu 14.04 installation, I had a horrible time getting the graphics to work (I had several failed attempts at manually installing a driver until one finally worked), so I wouldn't be surprised if "graphics throwing a temper tantrum again" is the root of my troubles.

---

Edit:
I've fixed my bug troubles, so there's no longer any urgency in this question. I'm still curious, however, what the difference is. Also, while I'm not confident, I think the question in the comment I posted might be correct. tl;dr: the post suggests that they're different kernels.

Comment: I may have found a similar question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/329303/refind-showing-multiple-ubuntu-after-update